# Parse background job not correctly querying all Users

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to follow Parse's documentation/examples for running a query within a background job. What I want to do is query through all `User`s in the database, and run a query on `matchCenterItem`s associated with each `User`.

When I run this job, it logs `status.success`, however it doesn't go past `console.log('about to start the matchCenterItem query');`.

`query.find().then(function(results)` never runs, giving me the impression that I'm either structuring the `matchCenterItem` query incorrectly, or not querying through each `User` the proper way. I've only posted the relevant code snippet in order to keep things concise, but I'll gladly post the entire code of the background job if needed.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {

    //Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    console.log('background task started');
    //defines which parse class to iterate through


    //Query through all users 
    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    //For every user, do the following:
    usersQuery.each(function(user) {
      //query through all their matchCenterItems
      var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
      var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);

      // promise and searchterm arrays to be filled
      var promises = [];
      var searchTerms = [];

      //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
      query.limit(10);

      console.log('about to start the matchCenterItem query');

      query.find().then(function(results) {

        console.log('matchCenterItem query results:' + results);
        if (results.length > 0){ 

      //code cut off here
```

Comment: Are you returning anything from the `function(user) { }`? Since this is doing async work it needs to return a promise so the `each()` knows when each piece of work is done.

Comment: @ChrisSainty That's a good point. How would I go about doing that correctly?

Comment: @ChrisSainty Here's the full code if you need more context: http://codeshare.io/bN03v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay that is a lot of code and deeply nested.

From what I can see, you need to return two promises that are currently not being returned

```
27: return query.find().then(function(results) {
104: return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(results) {
```

In addition you have two promises towards the bottom that should either be chained together with a `then()`, or made parallel with `Parse.Promise.when`. In either case the result needs to be returned also.

```
232: newMComparisonArray.save({
244: mComparisonQuery.find({
```

So the problems with the code are simply related to promises being created but no waited for. Whenever you create a promise you should be thinking about who is listening for the promise to complete and ensure the promise is returned to the listener.

Comment: Ah I see. What do you mean by "made parallel with"?

Comment: `Parse.Promise.when` is used when you have many promises and you want them all to start happening at the same time, instead of waiting for each other. So when you have two more more tasks to run, and they do not need to happen one after the other, you can use `Parse.Promise.when` to achieve that.

Comment: Makes sense. Would that be relevant in this case, where `newMComparisonArray.save` happens within `mComparisonQuery.find`, rather than after it as you mentioned?